# PySpark: Formatting JSON before input to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a Spark dataframe which contains a list of labelled tweets from a number of separate JSON files. I've tried simply using `spark.read.json(files, multiLine=True)` but I end up with a `_corrupted_record` in some files, there's something Spark doesn't seem to like about the format (JSON is valid, I've checked).

The following is a representation of the format of each JSON object per file that I'm dealing with:

```
{"annotator": {
  "eventsAnnotated" : [ {...} ],
  "id" : "0939"
},
"events": [
{"eventid": "039393",
"tweets": [
{
  "postID" : "111",
  "timestamp" : "01/01/01",
  "categories" : [ "Category" ],
  "indicatorTerms" : [ ],
  "priority" : "Low",
  "text" : "text"
},
...]
```

However, I'm only interested in the `tweets` section of the JSON and can disregard `eventid`, or anything included in `annotator`:

```
"tweets": [
{
  "postID" : "111",
  "timestamp" : "01/01/01",
  "categories" : [ "Category" ],
  "indicatorTerms" : [ ],
  "priority" : "Low",
  "text" : "text"
},
...]
```

I'd like that to end up in a Spark dataframe in which `postID`, `timestamp`, `categories`, `indicatorTerms`, `priority`, and `text` are my columns and each row corresponds to one of these JSON entries.

I guess what I'm asking is how can I read these files into some sort of temporary structure where I can stream, line-by-line, each tweet and then transform that into a Spark dataframe? I've seen some posts about RDDs but only managed to confuse myself, I am pretty new to Spark as a whole.

Comment: do the `tweets` field from different files have the same schema(i.e. array of structs with same field-definitions, some fields might missing but data types must be consistent). Also are they at the same node position from the root, i.e. using JSONPath like `$.events[*].tweets` or they are different in various files?

Comment: Yes, the schema is exactly the same across all files. As for the position, they are also the same. There may be more events or more `annotator` entries but in terms of structure they are identical.